# Why does Apache serve from /usr/local/apache2/htdocs and not /var/www/html?

Tags: apache

In `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` I have the following config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

However, when I visit `localhost`, I get the "It works!" page, which is located in `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs`. (I've verified this by changing the file's contents and refreshing the page.)

Why is Apache serving from `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs` instead of `/var/www/html` as specified in the config?

Comment: Is /etc/apache2/httpd.conf referencing sites-enabled/*.conf by Includes? Not every distribution uses this method, in case you set it up yourself. And do you have another virtualhost in there which is superceding this one (with a more specific servername)? And finally, did you restart apache after making this change to 000-default.conf?

Comment: I don't have an /etc/apache2/httpd.conf but I do have /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, and yes, it has IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf. For context, all this is happening inside a [Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd). I didn't restart apache because I didn't set 000-default.conf that way, it just came that way. No superseding VirtualHost that I know of.

Comment: I believe I've found a clue. There's a file called `/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` which contains `DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"`. This must be what's doing it. I wonder if I can somehow get `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` to override `/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`.

Comment: Do you maybe have a file like /etc/default/apache that is specifying the config path in an environment variable?  In any case if you add `IncludeOptional /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*.conf` to `/usr/loca/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` as it is now, it should pickup your file.

Comment: Also  I suppose it depends how you started apache. If you used a script instead of a supplied systemd or init file, it may be missing something like `-d /etc/apache2` or explicitly setting it to /usr/local

Comment: Did you figure out what the issue is? I am also having this problem

Answer (score 0):

Look for a symlink on either /var/www or /var/www/html.

Comment: AFAICT there are no symlinks.